# React native: Images are not getting rendered

Tags: image, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

In react native , I am simply loading an network image.

Code:

```
 const { width, height } = Dimensions.get('window');
 const prod= [];
    const prodName = '';
    const url = '';
    const results = [];
    class Product extends Component {
        renderWhenAPISuccess(){
          results=this.props.product;
          for(var i =1; i<results.length; i++){
            prodName = results[i].prodName;
            url = results[i].url;
            prod.push(
              <View key={i}>
               <Image
                  style={{ width: width/2, height: width/2}}
                  resizeMode={'contain'}
                  /*source={require('../img/bangalore1.jpg')}*/
                  source={{ uri: "https://example.in" + url }}
               ></Image>
               <Text>{prodName}</Text>
              </View>
           )
         }
       }

    render(){
      if(//network success){
        this.renderWhenAPISuccess();
      }
     return (
         {
            !isNetworkSuccess && 
             <View>
                <Text>Wait for api success</Text>
             </View>
         }
         {
          isNetworkSuccess &&
            <View>
              <ScrollView removeClippedSubviews={true}>
                  {prod}
              </ScrollView>
            </View>
         }
        );
     }
    }
```

When I am having multiple images in a screen, the images are not getting rendered.

When image source is like this :

> source={require('../img/bangalore1.jpg')}

its rendering properly. How can I render the images properly?  Is there any library to render network images ?

Please ignore the part of calling api and storing it. Everything is working fine except rendering of few images . Please note that randomly images are not rendering.

Comment: I think you need to set up both height and width. Take a look at [Official Docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image.html)

Comment: Please check the updated code. I am taking the window height and width, then also images are not rendering.

Comment: is the text "Wait for api success" printed instead?

Comment: Before calling wait for api is called, after getting response I am getting only the product names, which I fetched from the api. Please ignore the api calling part , its working perfectly with redux.

Comment: what is the full url for the picture?

Comment: its with https only .

Comment: you can still post it...

Comment: any updates? I got same issues

Answer (score 4):

Finally I have found a solution.

> Use react-native-cached-image for fetching mutiple images.

```
<CachedImage
     style={{ width: width / 2.35, height: 180, }}
     source={{
     uri: "https://myproject.in" + productDetail.image_url
    }}
></CachedImage>
```

Comment: Hey, would you mind to explain why and what you have found? It is interesting for me. Thanks!

Comment: Sure, it will help you to render the images, which is not possible using Images component of react native. In case of multiple images rendering.This component will help the network image will be downloaded and cached on the device, and best thing is for the same url image will always result in an instant load.

Comment: I have preloaded 12 images and each is loaded in each page. Some time 10 images shows some time 11 images are showing.I have checked if the images is unavailable in the link but it was there.This is randomly occuring to me. This is also not helping what should i do?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and I've searched almost all the web for that.
I tried [`FlatList`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html) and [`ListView`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/listview.html) and [`RecyclerListView`](https://github.com/Flipkart/recyclerlistview)
Finally I **found the solution my self**. It was very ***simple***.
*You don't even need **`react-native-cached-image`** or any third-party component*.
When you want to show list of images (like Instagram) all need to do is:

1- Instead of rendering the data inside the **rowRenderer** function just write another child component and send the data via `props` like this:

```
render() {
    return (
            <View style={{flex: 1}}>
                <RecyclerListView
                    ref="memories_ref"
                    forceNonDeterministicRendering={true}
                    layoutProvider={this._layoutProvider}
                    dataProvider={this.state.dataProvider}
                    rowRenderer={this.renderMemories.bind(this)}
                    renderAheadOffset={50}
                />
            </View>
        );

}
```

2- And in rowRenderer just load your child component:

```
renderMemories(type, item) {
    return (<Memory liked={liked} item={item}/>);
}
```

Comment: forceNonDeterministicRendering={true}, It is strictly prohibited for better performance. So, RecyclerListView is the solution?

Comment: I had dynamic height list so thad I had to use this property (`forceNonDeterministicRendering={true}`) but if you have static height for each item you can remove it.

Comment: Thanks. @S.Hossein

Answer (score 1):

What I see is without calling `this.setState({...})` the render method gets never called, so you will never see nothing being rendered.
If I were you I would do some changes:

1. Call the API in `componentDidMount`
2. Set your state before and after using `this.setState` so render is called
3. Render depending on the state, not in vars. This is one of the most important concepts behind ReactNative.

I can't set an environment right now, so I could not test the snippet, but it should look like this:

```
const { width, height } = Dimensions.get('window');

class Product extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.renderWhenAPISuccess = this.renderWhenAPISuccess.bind(this);
    }

    renderWhenAPISuccess(){
        let prod= [];
        let results = this.props.product;
        for(var i =1; i<results.length; i++){
            prod.push(
              <View key={i}>
                <Image
                  style={{ width: width/2, height: width/2}}
                  resizeMode={'contain'}
                  /*source={require('../img/bangalore1.jpg')}*/
                  source={{ uri: "https://example.in" + results[i].url }}
                />
                <Text>{results[i].prodName}</Text>
              </View>
            )
        }

        //You always need to return the component to be rendered
        //and in your case you will also need a ScrollView or a FlatList
        return (
            <ScrollView style={{flex: 1}} horizontal={true}>
                {prod}
            </ScrollView>
        );
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        //Call your API
        this.setState({isNetworkSuccess: false}, () => {
            fetch('URL')
              .then(products => this.setState({products, isNetworkSuccess: true}))
              .catch(ex => this.setState({error: ex}))
        });
    }

    render(){
        if(this.props.isNetworkSuccess){
            return this.renderWhenAPISuccess();
        }

        return (
             <View>
                <Text>Wait for api success</Text>
             </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Try fixing an image using `source={require('...')}` first in order to see the changes, and then move ahead with the URL.

Try this code and let me know, sadly, I cannot test it right now, so...

Comment: yes I am even getting the image url on the image, please ignore the updating component and fetching data code part. I didnt wrote the whole code here to keep the codes small. I am even getting few images rendered, but not all. The issue is when getting multiple number of images in a single page, all images are not getting displayed.

Comment: I went through this link also, it didnt helped. https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/10569

Comment: Well, then you need a list of images, that's your problem! Wrap them in a ScrollView or a FlatList! The link you past is using an ScrollView as well.

Comment: please check the updated code. I have put the image list in a scroll view with removeClippedSubviews={true}

Comment: Yes, but you are still forgetting to set the new state using this.setState. That's why I've change your code. React renders based on state changes, so you need to update the state to let react to realize about those changes

Comment: I am using redux, and its updaing the component automatically, that is why few images are getting rendered.

Comment: Ok, that's another song and makes sense. Would you mind to post the whole component please? It's mostly related to the style I guess

Comment: Another aspect to take into account is that `removeClippedSubviews` is experimental, so let's try to use a common vertical `ScrollView` to see if it is working, then we can focus on `horizontal` and `removeClippedSubviews` props.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152211/discussion-between-subhajit-and-facundo-la-rocca).

Answer (score 1):

class Offers extends Component {

```
constructor(props) {  
  super(props); 
  this.state = {
    entries: [
        {
            title: 'Beautiful',
            thumbnail: 'https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/airplane.png'
        },
        {
            title: 'Earlier this',
            thumbnail: 'https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/baboon.png'
        },
        {
            title: 'White Pocket',
            thumbnail: 'https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/boat.png'
        },
      ],
  }  

}

_renderItem = ({item, index}, parallaxProps) => {
    return (
        <View style={styles.item}>
            <ParallaxImage
                source={{ uri: item.thumbnail }}
                containerStyle={styles.imageContainer}
                style={styles.image}
                parallaxFactor={0.4}
                {...parallaxProps}
            />
            <Text style={styles.title}>{ item.title }</Text>
        </View>
    );
}
render() {
    return (
        <Carousel
          ref={(c) => { this._carousel = c; }}
          data={this.state.entries}
          renderItem={this._renderItem}
          sliderWidth={screenWidth}
          itemWidth={screenWidth - 60}
          hasParallaxImages={true}
          useScrollView={true}
        />
    );
  }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

largeHeap="true" worked for me in androidmanifest.xml

Answer (score 0):

Try using [resizeMethod](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image.html#resizemethod) in your `Image` like so:

```
<Image
   resizeMethod="resize"`
   ...
 />
```

(Careful, don't mix it with `resizeMode`)

Then your images should get rendered again.